# Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register.html

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Working on *django * on a test app, while creating a subpage as register in index/homepage, facing an error as follows:

Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
[name='index']
admin/
accounts
^media/(?P.*)$
The current path, accounts/register.html, didn’t match any of these.

**views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def register(request):
    return render(request,'register.html')
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path("register",views.register, name="register") 
]
```

**mysite url.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include , path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('Sell.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts', include('accounts.urls'))
]

urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**index.html**:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="header_section_top">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                     <div class="custom_menu">
                        <ul>
                           <li><a href="#">Best Sellers</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">Gift Ideas</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">New Releases</a></li>
                           <li><a href="accounts\register.html">Register</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">Customer Service</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

#Although the register.html is in a templates folder but i tried it too but still not working.

**Register.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content="IE=edge">
    <title>Register</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action='register' method='post'>
        {% csrf_token %}

        <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name"><br/>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"><br/>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><br/>
        <input type="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email"><br/>
        <input type="Password" name="Pasword1" placeholder="Pasword"><br/>
        <input type="Password" name="Password2" placeholder="Confirm Pasword"><br/>
        
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the django template tag:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a></li>
```

which refers to the "name" in the path definition in urls.py